# Place the labels on the bar and line chart separately

Tags: charts, chart.js

I would like to know how to position the labels on the bar and line chart separately.

On the bar chart I would like to put the labels above the bars and on the line chart I would put the labels below the line.

```js
 const ctx = document.getElementById("barCanvas");
/* ------------------------ DATA ----------------------------------- */
let l1 = []; let l2 = []; for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { l1.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1); l2.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1);}
const date = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

/* ------------------------ BAR --------------------- */
const barChart = {
  type: "bar",
  yAxisID: "y",
  label: "Weekly Sales",
  data: l1,
  backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"
  ],
  borderColor: ["rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)", "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"],
  borderWidth: 1,
  order: 2
};

/* ------------------------ LINE --------------------- */
const lineChart = { type: "line", label: "Line Dataset", data: l2, yAxisID: "rel", order: 1, tension: 0.4 };

/* ------------------------ SCALE --------------------- */
const scalesChart = {
  y: {
    //anchor: 'end',
    //align: 'top',
    type: "linear",
    position: "left",
    beginAtZero: true
  },
  rel: {
    type: "linear",
    position: "right",
    beginAtZero: true,
    suggestedMin: 0, suggestedMax: Math.max(...l2) + 3,
    grid: {display: false}
  }
};

const mixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  data: {
    datasets: [barChart, lineChart],
    labels: date
  },
  options: {
    scales: scalesChart,
    plugins: {
      datalabels:{
        //y: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        //}
      }
      
    }
  },
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Graph</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Graphique</h1>
    <div class="chart-container">
      <canvas id="barCanvas" aria-label="chart" role="img"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the bars, the labels seem to appear above by default.
otherwise, you can do the same as the line options, as follows.

for the line, you can use `datalabels` option `align`
add the option(s) to the `lineChart` constant, as follows...
here, I've added `offset` to add a little distance from the point.

```
const lineChart = {
  type: "line",
  label: "Line Dataset",
  data: l2,
  datalabels: {       <-- add options here
    align: 'bottom',
    anchor: 'end',
    offset: 8
  },
  yAxisID: "rel",
  order: 1,
  tension: 0.4
};
```

see following working snippet...

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("barCanvas");
/* ------------------------ DATA ----------------------------------- */
let l1 = [];
let l2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  l1.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  l2.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}
const date = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

/* ------------------------ BAR --------------------- */
const barChart = {
  type: "bar",
  yAxisID: "y",
  label: "Weekly Sales",
  data: l1,
  backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"],
  borderColor: ["rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)", "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"],
  borderWidth: 1,
  order: 2
};

/* ------------------------ LINE --------------------- */
const lineChart = {
  type: "line",
  label: "Line Dataset",
  data: l2,
  datalabels: {
    align: 'bottom',
    anchor: 'end',
    offset: 8
  },
  yAxisID: "rel",
  order: 1,
  tension: 0.4
};

/* ------------------------ SCALE --------------------- */
const scalesChart = {
  y: {
    //anchor: 'end',
    //align: 'top',
    type: "linear",
    position: "left",
    beginAtZero: true
  },
  rel: {
    type: "linear",
    position: "right",
    beginAtZero: true,
    suggestedMin: 0,
    suggestedMax: Math.max(...l2) + 3,
    grid: {
      display: false
    }
  }
};

const mixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  data: {
    datasets: [barChart, lineChart],
    labels: date
  },
  options: {
    scales: scalesChart,
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        //y: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        //}
      }

    }
  },
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Graph</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Graphique</h1>
  <div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="barCanvas" aria-label="chart" role="img"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```